# Apache Cordova create common Js File

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new with Apache Cordova.
I want to create an app that can display many different webpages (one at a time) going on respective url, something like this:

index.html

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

index.js

```
...
switch(choice) {
case 1: 
  window.location="www.site1.com";
  break;
case 2: 
  window.location="www.site1.com";
  break;
case 3: 
  window.location="www.site1.com";
  break;
}
...
```

When I go on a website the other code that I write in the index.js will not work, how can I add a common .js for all pages?

Thanks

Comment: You can't unless the sites are all on a shared domain. Look up the Same-Origin Policy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy You can load all the sites in an iframe, but you can't effect the inner contents with JS

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to to do, but jquery mobile lets you have multiple 'internal' pages in a single html file, e.g. see [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html)